# react admin datagrid exempt column from being forward to another view

Tags: datagrid, react-admin

I used react admin's data grid to show my data from api and put functionField with Delete mui on it. I would like to exempt one column like to toggle DeleteButton to render modal but in datagrid I always forwarded to another view, here's my sample component

```
            <List
                actions={<ListActions />}
                bulkActionButtons={false}
                {...props}
                sort={{
                    field: 'name',
                    order: 'DESC'
                }}
                empty={true}
      
            >
                <Datagrid rowClick="edit" >
                    <TextField label="Account No." source="account_number" emptyText="-" />
                    <TextField label="Account ID" source="accountId" emptyText="-" />
                    <TextField label="Balance" source="balance" emptyText="-" />
                    <FunctionField label="Action"  render={ (rec: any) => <Delete onClick={() => handleDelete(rec)} /> }  />
                </Datagrid>
                
            </List>
```

but each time I click the delete button it redirect to edit view thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you specified `<Datagrid rowClick="edit">`, any click on a row redirects the user to the corresponding edit view. If that's not what you want, you have two options:

- remove the `rowClick="edit"` bit, and add an `<EditButton>` on every row instead.
- in your click event handler, cancel event propagation to avoid that it's handled by DatagridRow after you handle it.

```js
<Delete onClick={(event) => {
    handleDelete(rec);
    event.stopPropagation();
}} />
```

Comment: thanks I applied this one and it works as I expected to be